# Regex in R lookbehind assertion

Tags: r, regex, lookbehind

I'm trying to do some pattern matching with the `extract` function from `tidyr`.  I've tested my regex in a regex practice site, the pattern seems to work, and I am using a `lookbehind assertion`.

I have the following sample text:

```
=[\"{ Key = source, Values = web,videoTag,assist }\",\"{ Key = type, 
Values = attack }\",\"{ Key = team, Values = 2 }\",\"{ Key = 
originalStartTimeMs, Values = 56496 }\",\"{ Key = linkId, Values = 
1551292895649 }\",\"{ Key = playerJersey, Values = 8 }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationStartX, Values = 3.9375 }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationStartY, Values = 0.739376770538243 }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationStartDeflected, Values = false }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationEndX, Values = 1.7897727272727275 }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationEndY, Values = -1.3002832861189795 }\",\"{ Key = 
attackLocationEndDeflected, Values = false }\",\"{ Key = lastModified, 
Values = web,videoTag,assist
```

I want to grab the numbers following `attackLocationX` (all numbers following any text about an attack location.

Using the following code with lookbehind assertion, however, I get no results:

```
df %>% 
extract(message, "x_start",'((?<=attackLocationStartX,/sValues/s=/s)[0- 
9.]+)')
```

This function will return `NA` if no pattern match is found, and my target column is all `NA` values despite having tested the pattern on `www.regexr.com`. According to the documentation, `R` pattern matching supports lookbehind assertions so I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: Why are you looking behind? It seems that you are looking for "Values" following `attackLocationStartX`.

Comment: Try `extract(message, "x_start", "attackLocationStartX\\s*,\\s*Values\\s*=\\s*(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)")`. It extracts `3.9375`. Is it expected? Or do you need some other outcome?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works perfectly.  What does `-?` do?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `-?` is an optional hyphen. I posted an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55282438/3832970), by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to match whitespace you need `\s`, not `/s`.

You do not have to use a lookbehind here, as the `extract` will return captured substrings if capturing group(s) are used in the pattern.

Use

```
df %>% 
  extract(message, "x_start", "attackLocationStartX\\s*,\\s*Values\\s*=\\s*(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)")
```

Output: `3.9375`.

The regex may also look like `"attackLocationStartX\\s*,\\s*Values\\s*=\\s*(-?\\d[.0-9]*)"`.

As the `(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)` part is captured, only the text in this group will be the output.

**Pattern details**

- `(-?\d+\.\d+)` - a capturing group thst matches

  - `-?` - an optional hyphen (`?` means *1 or 0 occurrences*)
  - `\d+` - 1 or or digits (`+` means *1 or more*)
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or or digits
- `\d[.0-9]*`  - a digit (`\d`), followed with 0 or more dots or digits (`[.0-9]*`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the lookbehind part, but in R, you need to escape backslashes. This isn't obvious if you are using a regex checker that isn't R-specific.

More info [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions).

So you might want your regex to look something like:

```
"attackLocationStartX,\\sValues\\s=\\s)[0-9.]+"
```